# Insert into .. one table to another table w/ 2 conditions

Tags: mysql

Trying to send data from players_to_pass to players. Im looking to have the players table to append data and pass duplicates. I keep getting a syntax error :

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '/T, Ht, Wt, DOB) SELECT Name, B/T, Ht, Wt, DOB FROM players_to_pass WHERE Name, ' at line 1

```
INSERT INTO players (Name, B/T, Ht, Wt, DOB) SELECT Name, B/T, Ht, Wt, DOB FROM players_to_pass WHERE Name, DOB NOT IN (SELECT Name, DOB FROM players)
```

Thank you for any help or criticism

Comment: In addition to backtick-quoting the `\`B/T\``, you will probably need to surround the double `IN()` clause with `()` as `WHERE (Name, DOB) NOT IN (SELECT ...)` . You don't have the first pair of `()` as it is now.

Comment: i guess this is a duplicate and i can't really argue that. I didn't find that in my search for why i was having the issue. But Michaels comments answered my question so thank you Michael!